# alarm stops launching when I exit the application

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an alarm (repetitive every 1min) defined in an android application. It works fine when the app is open but once I hit the exit button (the arrow to the right), it launches fine two more times and doesn't launch again. Do you know why this might be happening? this is the alarm class that calls the timer class to create the alarm:

```
public class Alarma {
    private int ano;
    private int mes;
    private int dia;
    private int hora;
    private int minuto;
    private int segundo;
    private Context contexto;

    public Alarma(Context contexto,int ano, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto, int segundo) {
        this.ano = ano;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.hora = hora;
        this.minuto = minuto;
        this.segundo = segundo;
        this.contexto=contexto;
        crearAlarma(contexto,ano,mes,dia,hora,minuto,segundo);
    }
    public Calendar crearCalendario(int ano, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto, int segundo)
    {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set (Calendar.YEAR, ano);
        cal.set (Calendar.MONTH, mes);
        cal.set (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dia);
        cal.set (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hora);
        cal.set (Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);
        cal.set (Calendar.SECOND, segundo);
        return cal;
    }
    public void crearAlarma(Context contexto,int ano,int mes,int dia,int hora, int minuto,int segundo)
    {
        Intent intentoLanzar = new Intent(contexto.getApplicationContext(), Temporizador.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(contexto, 0, intentoLanzar, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendario= crearCalendario(ano,mes,dia,hora,minuto,segundo);
        //AlarmManager aMan = (AlarmManager)contexto.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        AlarmManager aMan = (AlarmManager)contexto.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //aMan.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendario.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
        aMan.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendario.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60, pIntent);
    }

}
```

this is the timer class: (which is a broadcast receiver that triggers a notification when the alarm is raised)

```
public class Temporizador extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Context contexto;
    private final static String CHANNEL_ID="NOTIFICACION";
    private final static int NOTIFICACION_ID=0;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  {

        this.contexto=context;
        createNotificationChannel(contexto);
        createNotification(contexto);
        Toast.makeText(contexto.getApplicationContext(), "Alerta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void createNotificationChannel(Context contexto) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            CharSequence name="Medicacion";
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel=new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)contexto.getSystemService(contexto.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }

    private void createNotification(Context contexto) {
        Intent intentoClickNotification = new Intent(contexto, OnClickNotification.class);
        PendingIntent pIntentClickNotification=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(contexto, 1, intentoClickNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(contexto.getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_medical_services_24);
        builder.setContentIntent(pIntentClickNotification);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentTitle("Hora de la pastilla");
        builder.setContentText("No te olvides de tu medicacion");
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
        builder.setLights(Color.WHITE,500,500);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat= NotificationManagerCompat.from(contexto.getApplicationContext());
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICACION_ID,builder.build());
    }
}
```

and this is how I create the alarm in the mainactivity:

```
Alarma alarma=new Alarma(this,2022,Calendar.FEBRUARY,27,18,49,00);
```

and this is the piece of code for the temporizador in the manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".Temporizador"
    android:process=":remote" />
<receiver
```

It gives me the feeling that once the application has been exited, after a certain time it is eliminated, since I still receive two alarms after exiting the application and no more. a greeting.

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to activate the option `without restrictions` in the powers save battery options.